# Data from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in the same database. With same constraint and same column name. Both tables have primary key with auto-increment and I want insert data directly from one table to the other by using following query.

```
insert into table_name select * from table_name
```

all data get inserted into table one but auto-increment is not happening.

in image their is same problem(table in image is created for test)

[image]

Comment: Try something like  this `INSERT INTO table_destination SELECT column_name1,column_name2,column_name3 FROM table_src;`

Comment: sorry i want to combine two tables

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use * you should use the column name without  the id  (therwise you insert the selected id and is not performed the autoincrement)

```
 insert into table_name ( col1, col2) 
 select col1, col2 from table_name;
```